# Swift crash with nil coalescing operator EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000` on the following line and am not sure why.

```
let personManager = PersonManager.shared ?? PersonManager(user: firebaseUser)
```

...in this code block...

```
AppUtils.getFirebaseUser { firebaseUser in
    let personManager = PersonManager.shared ?? PersonManager(user: firebaseUser)
    if personManager.peopleHaveLoaded() {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

PersonManager.swift

```
class PersonManager: NSObject {
    public static var shared: PersonManager?
    init(user: User) {
        ...
        super.init()
        PersonManager.shared = self
    }

    ...
}
```

What I assumed would happen is the if `PersonManager.shared` is `nil` then the nil coalescing operator would call the `init` function, so either way it was guaranteed to have an instance.

I know that you generally see that crash when you have a dangling pointer, but I thought the nil coalescing operator `??` would take care of that. Any ideas on why it's crashing?

Comment: On my playground, it works -- when I skip all that firebase stuff. Please try to also remove all unnecessary code, expecial 3rd party libraries, and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to build a singleton. Check out https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift to an authoritative answer how to do this in Swift without running into race conditions.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFriese. Yeah, I guess I didn't call out that I'm using a singleton but you're correct. That tutorial had some helpful reminders about why singletons are an anti-pattern and how to set them up properly. I have a little bit different need, in that I have to pass in an authenticated user + want a singleton, but I think I know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

it could be the race condition issue. The PersonManager.shared is accessed on two thread at the same time.